# Teamcity Step tests (Command Line) failed when testing an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, teamcity, pushwoosh, xctool

I am trying to run tests automatically using Teamcity, but it seems that when the agent is compiling the project, it is not done correctly because when I run the command like for running test, I am getting the following error:

```
fatal error: 'Pushwoosh/PushNotificationManager.h' file not found
#import <Pushwoosh/PushNotificationManager.h>
[16:48:51][Step 2/2]         ^
[16:48:51][Step 2/2] 1 error generated.
```

However, when I run manually the same commands I get no errors, but my test running. The application that I want to run was written in objective-c, and the command lines I am using are the following:

```
$ git clone REPOSITORY_URL (runs sucessfully)
$ pod install              (runs sucessfully)
$ xctool -workspace Supermaxi.xcworkspace    -scheme Supermaxi     test -only FunctionalTests:TestCase000_Registration/test00_WrongEmail  -sdk iphonesimulator (fails and I get the previous described error)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being helped by I friend of mine, we found the solution to this issue in this [link](https://medium.com/@Ashton/teamcity-and-checked-in-pods-8383e8f25590).

It turns out that the main problem was, as the link states, that *CocoaPods uses symbolic links in it’s directory structure, and TeamCity can have trouble copying symbolic links in the VCS checkout to build agent*, so I had to set the Version Control Settings of Teamcity as it is explained in the previous link.

Therefore, I have just changed the VCS checkout mode from **Automatically on server** to **Automatically on agent (if supported by VCS roots)**. After that I run the agent again, and it worked properly.